# I am using eclipse and getting this error can someone tell me where I am going wrong

Tags: java, eclipse

```
import java.util.Scanner;
package reviewDistance;

public class ReviewDistance {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sec1;
        int sec2;
        int sec3;
        int race;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the length of the first section of the race in kilometers:");
        sec1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the length of the second section of the race in kilometers:");
        sec2 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the length of the third section of the race in kilometers:");;
        sec3 = input.nextInt();
        input.close();

        race = sec1 + sec2 + sec3;
        System.out.println("Length of the race: " + race + "km");

    }

}
```

The error code I recieve is this and I don't know why! I am very new to Java

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

```
at reviewDistance.ReviewDistance.main(ReviewDistance.java:6)
```

Comment: Move "package" before "imports" at the top of your file :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
package reviewDistance;
```

change it to

```
package reviewDistance;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

package should be the first line in your jave file

Comment: I feel so silly now :P But its all about learning right ? :P thank you so much!